# Is it possible to use juvia with GitHub pages?

Tags: github

I have just created a new personal blog using GitHub's user pagers.  I would like to enable comments using [juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia) (I do not wish to use services like disqus).

The last step in the installation instructions for juvia is

> 7. Deploy this application to Phusion Passenger or whatever application server you prefer.

I am new to web content creation, so I'm not entirely sure of all the details of this. I see [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) that Phusion Passenger is a web app server. I understand that juvia requires a server to run and that I paste in some JavaScript into my posts to connect my posts to the server running juvia.

Here is my conditional question:

Can I use my GitHub pages account to run the juvia server?

- If so, how?
- If not, how do I go about using Phusion Passenger to host my juvia server (and subsequently use in my github pages)?  Will I need some sort of account? The instructions [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download/#open_source) don't mention creating an account which seems odd to me.

Comment: GitHub pages only support static file serving, so you won't be able to run the server (which looks like a Ruby app). Look for Ruby app hosting, but just be aware this will require configuration and probably need at least a few hundred dollars a year. Disqus may be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to host the server elsewhere as [Aaron Yodaiken](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43530/is-it-possible-to-use-juvia-with-github-pages#comment35051_43530) has pointed out. You can still use it on the static pages (the client-side javascript) but you will have to host the server elsewhere.

You could check out [railshosting](http://www.railshosting.org/) to find a hosting provider.